# How can Python guarantee memory safety?

Tags: python, memory, rust, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm learning Rust, and there, they reason that the following (python-equivalent) code is unsafe:

```py
vec = ['1', '2']
ref = vec[0]
vec.append('3')
```

The rationale is `ref` is a pointer to element in `vec`, however, `vec` is being mutated in the same scope via push command, which ***could*** involve moving the object to a whole new place in memory where there is enough space, leading to `ref` being a dangling pointer => therefore, compiler fails because of unsafe code.

I'm convinced by the logic, but exactly why is this never a problem in Python?
We still have `vec` in the heap and `ref` is a pointer, right?

Comment: Python seems like a poor choice for comparison. Python has an interpreter lock (GIL) that prevents that kind of thing. Because of this, most things in Python can be considered atomic. Libraries like `multithreading` and `multiprocessing` have their own interlocks that also prevent things like dangling references. To be fair, If you write a Python library in c, it's entirely possible to break things that way.

Comment: are you saying that the answer is simply "GIL" ?

Comment: For the most part, yeah.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the GIL. If this kind of code could create a dangling pointer, it could do so in single-threaded code.

Comment: @Ouroborus GIL is for multithreading but in lower level languages like C (with pointers to memory) this can become a problem without multithreading.

Comment: @user2357112 But it can't. `vec.append('3')` is effectively atomic.

Comment: @Ouroborus: If `ref` held a reference to storage owned by `vec`, and `vec.append('3')` invalidated that storage, `ref` would become a dangling reference regardless of whether `vec.append('3')` was atomic. It's not a matter of other code intervening during the append.

Comment: "vec" holds a reference (technically a pointer) to the list object which holds references to the contained string objects. Second line of code copies the first reference in the list to "ref". "ref" doesn't refer to the position in the list or the list at all but only to the object in the list. Changes to the list don't affect "ref".

Comment: @user2357112 So... If a python did a thing it doesn't do?

Comment: @Ouroborus: Yes, if Python did a thing it doesn't do. The questioner doesn't know what Python does or doesn't do, and they have in mind a counterfactual mental model that would be unsafe if Python behaved like that.

Comment: @Ouroborus If it helps, the Python code above is closer to this Rust code: `let mut v = Rc::new(vec![Rc::new("1".to_string()), Rc::new("2".to_string())]); let mut r = v[0].clone(); v.push(Rc::new("3".to_string()));` -- except the strings aren't mutable, and Python has a garbage collector to clean up while `Rc` is reference-counted.

Comment: @cdhowie the strings you're using here do match CPython's behaviour: you won't be able to mutate them through the rc in normal situations as they're not internally mutable, but if there's only one reference to the string `Rc::get_mut` allows mutating in-place, which some of cpython's C API do (which is why e.g. repeated concatenation is an amortised O(n) operation in cpython, not an O(n^2)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ref` is not a pointer to part of `vec`. It stores a reference to a string object. The list object referred to by `vec` also stores a reference to that string object. If the list needs to resize its underlying storage, it will copy the references it holds into a new buffer, but the string won't move, so `ref`'s reference can't be invalidated by this operation.

Comment: okay, suppose the string changed size, and therefore potentially gotten relocated, can we end up with dangling pointer?

Comment: or equivelently, if elements or integers in the first place, as opposed to strings.

Comment: @AlexDeft: Strings are immutable in Python. Even for mutable objects, resizing won't invalidate references. (At the implementation level, this is implemented by having a fixed-size "header" that doesn't move, which stores a pointer to a buffer that can be safely reallocated.)